# ros webrtc for peer to peer video streaming

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone used ROS WebRTC for peer to peer video streaming using ROS ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207688/ros-webrtc-for-peer-to-peer-video-streaming/) by [iamvajid](https://answers.ros.org/users/22252/iamvajid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robobee](https://answers.ros.org/users/22791/robobee/) on 2015-06-17**:
Please post the answer if you already got one. I am also interested in knowing about this.

**Comment by [ndeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/32105/ndeep/) on 2017-10-10**:
Any updates on this one? @robobee @iamvajid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used a different solution, kind of hybrid one. I used peer.js with roslibjs to get it working

---

Originally posted by [iamvajid](https://answers.ros.org/users/22252/iamvajid/) with karma: 36 on 2017-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zin Min](https://answers.ros.org/users/73667/zin-min/) on 2021-04-24**:
Could you share your design logic?